# Is "financial low" correct?

Tags: idiom-requests, translation

I need to translate *baja financiera* (Spanish) or *baixa financeira* (Portuguese) into English. That idiom is a noun phrase used to describe a partial or total payment of a purchase or sale.

I'll give an usage example of that idiom. If a client uses multiple payment methods (money, check, debit, credit), every *baja*/*baixa* consists of a paid amount and a payment method. If a client pays in multiple installments, every time an installment is paid a *baja*/*baixa* is done.

There's a related idiom *dar de baja* (Spanish) or *dar baixa* (Portuguese). That idiom is a verb phrase used to describe the action of registering a partial or total payment of a purchase or sale.

I found an English translation for the second idiom: *write off*. That translation is a verb, but I need a noun to translate the first idiom. I found the option *financial low*, but I don't know if that idiom has the meaning I expect.

Comment: "Write off" (and the corresponding noun, "writeoff") are used to indicate that a partial payment (or no payment at all) is being accepted, and the remainder of the value is considered lost - that is, if the value of the item or service being purchased is $100, and I accept $75 because I believe that I won't be able to get more than that from you, I "write off" the remaining $25. If this is semantically what _dar de baja/dar baixa_ imply, then it would be reasonable to translate _baja financiera/baixa financiera_ as "writeoff".

Comment: However, putting _baja financiera_ into Google Translate results in a translation of _financial loss_. That would imply that the translation of _dar de baja_ could as well be _taking a loss (on the transaction)_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, I gave an usage example.

Comment: Given your example, the proper translation of _baja financiera/baixa financeira_ would be _partial payment_, since you are not assuming a loss on the transaction. If the entire sale is paid for in a single payment, if that is still considered a _baja financiera/baixa financeira_, then a better translation would simply be _payment_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin semantic implication of *dar baixa* is more similar to "bookkeeping" I'd say, because it is not only used for payments, you can use it for all kinds of records in a journal, ledger or book of accounts.

Comment: The expression 'pay off [some of] the amount owing' is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Financial low** would not make sense. A **low** could mean many things, including a point where one has the *least* of something (financial low ~ point of least money). In English, that doesn't translate to payment. For example, if I'm paying for part of my college tuition, I may incidentally reach a *financial low*, that is, I don't have much money left in my account, but that's semantically separate from the act of payment or the transaction.

Regarding your usage example:

> I'll give an usage example of that idiom. If a client uses multiple payment methods (money, check, debit, credit), every baja/baixa consists of a paid amount and a payment method. If a client pays in multiple installments, every time an installment is paid a baja/baixa is done.

At least in American English, **payment** would denote giving money by some method. So they might pay in multiple installments, that is, each time they pay a **payment** is made. You could also say that with each installment a **transaction** is done. Because translation can be precise, context-specific work, I can't go further than that. I would look up the words in the contexts you're going for to see if they fit or if there are even more precise words or phrases that you'd prefer.